# Get element based on parent in JSoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

In the following XML I'd like to be able to get the content of the first title tag and not the second. Unfortunately the code prints the content of both title tags...

Any help would be great thanks!

```
String feedXMLString = "<entry><title>title 1</title><source><title>title 2</title></source></entry>";
    Document feedXML = Jsoup.parse(feedXMLString);

    NodeTraversor feedXMLTraversor = new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() {

          @Override
          public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
              if (node instanceof Element) {

                  String tagName = ((Element) node).tagName();                    
                  String parentTagName = ((Element) node).parent().tagName();

                  if (tagName.equals("title")) {          
                      if (parentTagName.equals("entry")) {
                          String title = ((Element) node).ownText();
                          System.out.println(title);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void head(Node node, int depth) { 
          }
        });
    feedXMLTraversor.traverse(feedXML.body());
```

Output is

```
title 1
title 2
```

I just want it to be title 1. I'm working under the assumption that the parent tag of the second title is `<source>`, but for some reason JSoup seems to think that it is `<entry>`

Thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the selector part of the Jsoup API? It's much much easier to use, it's cleaner, and I'm willing to bet that's faster as well. What I'd personally use is this:

```
//The line you already had
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(feedXMLString);

//This will get you all the titles
Elements elems = doc.select("title");

//And now you can proceed in various ways:
String title1stWay = elems.first().text();
String title2ndWay = elems.get(0).text();
```

Take a look here: [Jsoup Selector API](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: Cool. Went with this:  Elements entryElements = feedXML.select("entry");
  
  Iterator<Element> entryIterator = entryElements.iterator(); 
  while(entryIterator.hasNext()) {
      Element entryElement = entryIterator.next(); 
      System.out.print(entryElement.select("title").first().ownText());

  }

Comment: Well, if you put a first(); method inside a loop, it won't do you any good. You should use the first(); outside the loop, or else use the iterator.next(); method assigning the return to an Element

Answer (score 1):

try adding (below  `String tagName ,String parentTagName...`)

```
int numOfParents = ((Element) node).parents().size();
```

and changing

```
if (parentTagName.equals("entry"))
```

into

```
if (parentTagName.equals("entry") && (numOfParents == 1))
```

?

Comment: JSoup adds an html and body tag. But still if I print numbOfParents for each element I get this: 
"title 3
source 3
title 3
entry 2
body 1"     It seems that maybe JSoup is not parsing correctly? How can both titles have the same number of parents?

Comment: try to print `((Element) node).parents()` and see if the parents are the same for both titles...

Comment: Yes, they both have the same parents, entry body and html. If I change the source tags to div tags then the program works as expected. I can only guess that JSoup is removing the source tags from the DOM, possibly because it thinks they are superfluous. Is there some way to prevent this? Or some other way to distinguish between the two title tags? I suppose if worse comes to worse I could just take the first title tag found in each entry...

Comment: This is weird... Well I'm not a jsoup Pro. so there might be other tricks